# Export object from .blend file to Unity, the object is flipped

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I'm trying to import objects from .blend file to Unity directly so that I can edit as I go. However after I fixed the orientation issue(I rotated the object -90 by x axis in blender and applied the rotation transformation), I got this.[image: Blender]

[image: Unity]

Also, when I add a box collider to it, the Y axis is flipped as well.

Comment: Btw, I have no idea why the object is not flipped in the scene, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general: Blender uses a different orientation (Z is up, Y is forward) then Unity (Z is forward, Y is up)

so by default you always have a rotation around the `X` axis of -90°.

Then additionally your model root is already rotated by `90°` in Blender so in order to see it the same way in Unity you additionally need to rotate by `-90°` which sums up to `-180` you have to set in Unity in order to see the same result in Unity.

Also as you noted yourself all your scales are inverted as well so this will cause additional problems.

---

I'ld recommend to always properly export your blender files to FBX and not directly use the .blend files.

There is always some trouble with that direct way and either orientation or scales (or both) gets messed up.

And even then it is tricky to get the export settings right.

You should use the [Blender to Unity FBX Exporter plug-in for Blender](https://github.com/EdyJ/blender-to-unity-fbx-exporter).

It takes care of all the axis orientation and scaling settings for you so you can't mess them up ;)

Comment: Thank you! I'll take your suggestion.

Comment: I just found out why it is flipped, my scaling factors are all negative.

Comment: I have so much trouble with Blender files in Unity, I'm probably going to just give up and use FBX too. It seems like there's no combination of rotations you can apply that always results in the model being the right way up. Sometimes rotating -90 x works, sometimes it doesn't, and I can't see any pattern to it.

Comment: @Ash I can totally feel you ^^